# How to do a culture invariant conversion from int to String in Java?

Tags: java, c#, type-conversion, invariantculture

For converting an integer to string in C# (with invariant culture), we do something like below:

```
int num = 123;
string numAsString = num.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Is there an equivalent of the above operation in Java or does `Integer.toString(int)` inherently does culture invariant conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> or does `Integer.ToString(int)` inherently does culture invariant conversion?

It does. The documentation isn't as clear as it might be, but it doesn't use any grouping separators, negative numbers are always prefixed with `'-'`, and ASCII digits are always used.